# Npgsql integration with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, npgsql

I have a project using the last version of EF CF with PostgreSQL and Npgsql.

My model looks like:

```
[Table("mytable")]
public class MyTable
{
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("mycolumn")]
    public string MyColumn { get; set; }
}
```

And the database/tables/columns has lowercase names like:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
{
    id serial,
    mycolumn character(50)
}
```

The Npgsql generates SQL commands with quotation marks so I must use the Data Annotations due the PostgreSQL characteristics, witch is annoying. However I would like to not use quotations delimited names in the database.

Is there a way to configure Npgsql to not include quotation marks when generate commands or force lowercase table/columns names in the generated SQL?

Comment: I'll have a look at that.

Comment: Hi Francisco, in EF6 it's possible to use conventions to lowercase table and column names instead add an attribute to each one so don't worry to much about this question. :)

Comment: Using the code conventions works. Luckily when Postgres sees that the column name is all lowercase it ignores the double quotes (So we still get the case folding at the query time), but it would be still nice to know how to turn off the doublequoting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I'm not missing something - you'd want some generic way `of changing the naming convention for tables`?

The EF6 has the `custom conventions` feature - it's still not official version, but if it works for you, some links...

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Conventions

In your case, you'd have to implement it for the class/`Type` I guess - e.g. (some pseudo code)...

1) implement `IConfigurationConvention<Type, EntityTypeConfiguration>` (you can check the EF source for `EntityConventionBase`)

2) In the `Apply` - change how the Table names are generated via configuration (`ToTable()`) - to something like `.ToLowerCase()`

3) add to conventions...

For example...

```
public class SmallCapsEntitiesConfigurationConvention
    : IConfigurationConvention<Type, EntityTypeConfiguration>
{
    public void Apply(Type memberInfo, Func<EntityTypeConfiguration> configuration)
    {
        configuration().ToTable(memberInfo.Name.ToLowerInvariant(), null);
    }
}
```

You can see one example here
http://blog.cincura.net/233167-custom-conventions-in-entity-framework-6-helping-firebird/

Otherwise, I have no idea about `Npgsql` / PostgreSQL - it did seem a bit 'raw' to me. But you can handle it on the EF side.

Comment: That's a nice way to solve my problem! However the EF6 is not released as stable and I can't use this version on my company. But I will keep this in mind anyway.

Comment: I know @MaxBündchen - but that's the best you get I think - short of any solutions on the PostgreSQL side

Comment: Hey, I have the same problem... and EF6 is out now! :D

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for EF Core.

Current code convert `tables`, `properties`, `keys` and `indexes` to snake case for `Postgre`, you can use it as a base for your custom conventions:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Npgsql;

namespace Database.Customization
{
    public class PostgreDbContext : DbContext
    {
        private static readonly Regex _keysRegex = new Regex("^(PK|FK|IX)_", RegexOptions.Compiled);

        public PostgreDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            FixSnakeCaseNames(modelBuilder);
        }

        private void FixSnakeCaseNames(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var mapper = new NpgsqlSnakeCaseNameTranslator();
            foreach (var table in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                ConvertToSnake(mapper, table);
                foreach (var property in table.GetProperties())
                {
                    ConvertToSnake(mapper, property);
                }

                foreach (var primaryKey in table.GetKeys())
                {
                    ConvertToSnake(mapper, primaryKey);
                }

                foreach (var foreignKey in table.GetForeignKeys())
                {
                    ConvertToSnake(mapper, foreignKey);
                }

                foreach (var indexKey in table.GetIndexes())
                {
                    ConvertToSnake(mapper, indexKey);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ConvertToSnake(INpgsqlNameTranslator mapper, object entity)
        {
            switch (entity)
            {
                case IMutableEntityType table:
                    var relationalTable = table.Relational();
                    relationalTable.TableName = ConvertGeneralToSnake(mapper, relationalTable.TableName);
                    if (relationalTable.TableName.StartsWith("asp_net_"))
                    {
                        relationalTable.TableName = relationalTable.TableName.Replace("asp_net_", string.Empty);
                        relationalTable.Schema = "identity";
                    }

                    break;
                case IMutableProperty property:
                    property.Relational().ColumnName = ConvertGeneralToSnake(mapper, property.Relational().ColumnName);
                    break;
                case IMutableKey primaryKey:
                    primaryKey.Relational().Name = ConvertKeyToSnake(mapper, primaryKey.Relational().Name);
                    break;
                case IMutableForeignKey foreignKey:
                    foreignKey.Relational().Name = ConvertKeyToSnake(mapper, foreignKey.Relational().Name);
                    break;
                case IMutableIndex indexKey:
                    indexKey.Relational().Name = ConvertKeyToSnake(mapper, indexKey.Relational().Name);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException("Unexpected type was provided to snake case converter");
            }
        }

        private string ConvertKeyToSnake(INpgsqlNameTranslator mapper, string keyName) =>
            ConvertGeneralToSnake(mapper, _keysRegex.Replace(keyName, match => match.Value.ToLower()));

        private string ConvertGeneralToSnake(INpgsqlNameTranslator mapper, string entityName) =>
            mapper.TranslateMemberName(ModifyNameBeforeConvertion(mapper, entityName));

        protected virtual string ModifyNameBeforeConvertion(INpgsqlNameTranslator mapper, string entityName) => entityName;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

If you are working with EF core 3 then `Relational()` will cause error as the method was removed lately. Change the definition of the `ConvertToSnake` function as following:

```
private void ConvertToSnake(INpgsqlNameTranslator mapper, object entity)
{
        switch (entity)
        {
            case IMutableEntityType table:
                table.SetTableName(ConvertGeneralToSnake(mapper, table.GetTableName()));
                if (table.GetTableName().StartsWith("asp_net_"))
                {
                    table.SetTableName(table.GetTableName().Replace("asp_net_", string.Empty));
                    table.SetSchema("identity");
                }

            break;
        case IMutableProperty property:
            property.SetColumnName(ConvertGeneralToSnake(mapper, property.GetColumnName()));
            break;
        case IMutableKey primaryKey:
            primaryKey.SetName(ConvertKeyToSnake(mapper, primaryKey.GetName()));
            break;
        case IMutableForeignKey foreignKey:
            foreignKey.SetConstraintName(ConvertKeyToSnake(mapper, foreignKey.GetConstraintName()));
            break;
        case IMutableIndex indexKey:
            indexKey.SetName(ConvertKeyToSnake(mapper, indexKey.GetName()));
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException("Unexpected type was provided to snake case converter");
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/21#issuecomment-376114368