# EF: Use reflection to build model for platform agnostic database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, reflection

My Code First EF application currently supports SQL Server and Oracle.
I have two different SQL scripts for each platform that basically go like this.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1(...etc.)
CREATE TABLE TABLE2(...etc)
```

The tables and attributes are all uppercase and so are the properties in my POCO class.

**Now**, for the next version I want to pick up support for PostgreSQL. I was able to get my same code to work by modifying my DDL to force the tables/attributes to be upper case.

e.g.
`create table "TABLE1"(...etc.)`

Of course, I don't want to make upper case objects in Postgres.
So I know I can write a bunch of code in my `OnModelCreating()` that's like

```
if(dbType == DbType.POSTGRES)
    modelBuilder.Entity<TABLE1>().ToTable("table1")
```

and I could also write code for each of the properties like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TABLE1>().Property(p => p.COLUMN1).HasColumnName("column1")
modelBuilder.Entity<TABLE1>().Property(p => p.COLUMN2).HasColumnName("column2")
//etc
```

I think an even more slick way would be to use reflection that:

1. For each table: set its table name ToLower()
2. For each attribute in each table, set its name ToLower()

Going to be working on this today, and will post an answer if I find something workable.

**Note:** It's probably worth mentioning that the reason uppercase objects in my POCO classes don't work with Postgres because the way Entity Framework does Linq to SQL is that it generates SQL with quotation marks around the tables and attributes. So this SQL generated by EF:

`SELECT "COLUMN1", "COLUMN2" FROM "TABLE1"`

forces the postgres database to look for upper case objects.

Comment: All databases use a form of quotation. In fact, the default for T-SQL is to use square brackets, *not* double quotes. This should be handled by the mapping infrastructure though, not your code. Which driver, data provider did you use?

Comment: EF6 supports custom conventions as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814612/npgsql-integration-with-entity-framework-code-first) shows how to change the convention for table names for PostgreSQL

Comment: Naming conventions... yes. that's exactly what I need...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Thanks so much for the tip, I ended up simplifying a bunch of my model builder code with the naming conventions functionality supported in EF6. :)